# How to disable warning in sp::merge()?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

I am using `sp::merge` to merge `SpatialPologynDataFrame` with data.frame:

```
z <- merge(x, y, by.x = "field1", by.y = "field2")
```

merge() annoys me with `Warning message: In .local(x, y, ...) : 12 records in y cannot be matched to x`, which I am very well aware of. How to make him quiet? I did try to put `all.y = FALSE`. It would feel kinda stupid to have to pre-filter y to only those who match to x. This is what merge is supposed to do, just without kidding :-)

PS: I didn't ask for global warning suppression, just how to disable in this function.

PS 2: I still don't understand why sp::merge() warns about this, when base::merge() doesn't!:

```
z <- merge(x@data, y, by.x = "field1", by.y = "field2") 
# spatial info dropped, base::merge() called, no warning now
```

Comment: You can wrap the call to `merge` in `suppressWarnings` to get rid of the warnings for just the call to `merge`.

Comment: I understand your frustration, and voted to reopen the question. But using so many exclamation marks makes it look like you are screaming in our faces :).

Comment: thanks @PaulHiemstra, I was screaming actually, and I am glad and honestly very nicely surprised it got reopened again. I suggest to cleanup this conversation now as the original reason disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

Just run this line on top of your script `options(warn=-1)`. To turn back on set `warn = 0` . I read this here on SO but couldn't actually find the link so posting the answer. But note this will switch off the warnings globally .

For single line you can use `suppressWarnings(yourcode)`. Hope this helps .

Comment: My original question is how to disable this particular warning only. Thanks a lot though, this might come in handy as the last resort...

Comment: +1, I would reverse the solutions, and put the `supressWarnings` first. This solves the problem of the OP.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, well, I'd say it is a very nice hack rather than a proper solution, which would be to persuade merge to not warn about *this* - since merge might issue different, possibly useful warnings as well, which you miss using this hack. I know I am perfectionist though. sp::merge() shouldn't warn or it should possibly be lower priority message than warning if that exists in R. I still don't understand why sp::merge() warns about this, when merge() doesn't!

Comment: Merge is a generic function with a very different set of code for spatial objects than for say data.frames. This explains why the merge on data.frames does not show a particular warning.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra well it's quite clear why base::merge doesn't show that warning.. and the argument is that sp::merge shoudln't have it for the exactly same reason